# multicast frames in Linux virtual-switch

Tags: linux, bridge

I have a network topology where in "Dell PE860" runs a Linux virtual-switch `br0`:

[image: Linux bridge drawing]

Now if I send an Ethernet frame to broadcast address from "IBM ThinkCentre":

```
17:10:23.569021 00:a1:ff:01:02:05 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 34: 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1:  ip-proto-0 0
```

..then I see this frame in both virtual-machines as I should. If I send an Ethernet frame to MAC address which is not know in `br0` MAC address table, then the `br0` also behaves correctly and floods the frame to all ports expect to one where the frame came in(`eth1` in this example). However, if I send a multicast frame from "IBM ThinkCentre":

```
17:17:05.513283 00:a1:ff:01:02:05 > 01:33:44:55:66:77, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 34: 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1:  ip-proto-0 0
```

..then for some reason Linux virtual-switch does not flood it to all the ports(except the one where the frame came in from). Why is that so? I would expect that switch handles multicast frames exactly like broadcast frames.

Answer (score 2):

In order to enable forwarding of multicast Ethernet frames, one needs to disable multicast snooping under `/sys/devices/virtual/net/<br_name>/bridge/multicast_snooping`.

Answer (score 0):

Multicast is send only to those port of the bride that have joined the multicast group. So unless there is a client interested in the multicast data on a port and has send an igmp join message to the bridge does not forward the mutlicast frame to the port.

Multicast snooping can be disabled under `/sys/devices/virtual/net/<br_name>/bridge/multicast_snooping`