# Multicast frames in Linux bridge dropped

Tags: linux, networking, bridge

I have one VM running on an x86 host using `libvirt`. The interface of the VM is created as follows :

```
<interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:d0:18:eb'/>
      <source bridge='intfe2'/>
      <target dev='vnet4'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <alias name='net4'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x09' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
```

`intfe2` = Linux bridge that exists on the host as follows:

```
# brctl show intfe2
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
intfe2          8000.90e2bab68ff8       no              enp2s0f0
                                                        vnet4
```

Now, LACP is configured inside the VM on interface `vnet4` and same has been configured on an actual router that uses the interface `enp2s0f0` of the host machine.

I can see multicast frames coming from both these interfaces on the host.

```
# tcpdump -ni vnet4 -e
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on vnet4, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
15:56:48.160017 34:30:b4:59:06:00 > 01:80:c2:00:00:02, ethertype Slow Protocols (0x8809), length 124: LACPv1, length 110
15:56:49.162163 34:30:b4:59:06:00 > 01:80:c2:00:00:02, ethertype Slow Protocols (0x8809), length 124: LACPv1, length 110

# tcpdump -ni enp2s0f0 -e
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enp2s0f0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
15:57:46.173002 ac:4b:c8:89:d7:c1 > 01:80:c2:00:00:02, ethertype Slow Protocols (0x8809), length 124: LACPv1, length 110
15:57:47.171282 ac:4b:c8:89:d7:c1 > 01:80:c2:00:00:02, ethertype Slow Protocols (0x8809), length 124: LACPv1, length 110
15:57:48.171252 ac:4b:c8:89:d7:c1 > 01:80:c2:00:00:02, ethertype Slow Protocols (0x8809), length 124: LACPv1, length 110
```

I'm running Ubuntu Xenial:

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

My questions are :

1. Why are they not flooded ?
2. Does linux bridge avoids forwarding L2 multicast frames ?

From some links like [multicast frames in Linux virtual-switch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192228/multicast-frames-in-linux-virtual-switch) I even disabled the IGMP snooping as follows :

```
echo "0" > /sys/devices/virtual/net/intfe2/bridge/multicast_snooping
```

Also toggling the values for `/sys/devices/virtual/net/intfe2/bridge/multicast_querier`

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue you're hitting is that, by default, a Linux bridge will not forward frames to a destination MAC address in the range 01:80:c2:00:00:00 through 01:80:c2:00:00:0f.  The IEEE reserved this block of addresses for protocols that must not be forwarded by a MAC bridge.  Protocols such as LLDP, LACP, xSTP, etc., are all in this range.

There's a nice IEEE write-up, [Standard Group MAC Addresses: A Tutorial Guide](https://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/tut/macgrp.pdf).  If you're up for it, it is possible to recompile the bridge kernel module to allow forwarding of these frames, but do so at your own peril!  You'll need to edit `<source_path>/net/bridge/br_private.h` and set the `#define` for `BR_GROUPFWD_RESTRICTED` to `0x0u`.  Compile and reload the driver, and then run:

```
echo 255 > /sys/class/net/<bridge_name>/bridge/group_fwd_mask
```

Note that this will let through not just LLDP, but spanning tree frames as well.  So be sure you don't introduce any bridging loops!

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult for me to understand exactly your setup with the available information. But I will give you my setup so you can look and compare. Essential for multicast on bridges is multicast snooping so the bridge knows which port has joined to a multicast group and can forward multicast streams only to this port. Default setting of multicast_snooping is on. So I do not disable it.

If I look at the settings of the interfaces on my bridge it shows me this:

```
host ~$  sudo bridge -d link show
3: enp1s0 state UP : <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 4
    hairpin off guard off root_block off fastleave on learning on flood on mcast_flood on
5: vnet0 state UNKNOWN : <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 100
    hairpin off guard off root_block off fastleave on learning on flood off mcast_flood on
```

Important is `mcast_flood on` which is default setting. `fastleave on` is nice to have but not needed for multicast. It's only for leaving a multicast group without a timeout on the bridge if a guest leaves the group. `flood on/off` belongs to unicast and is here not relevant.

If a guest joins a multicast group (starting a multicast client program) the bridge snoops it and add it to its multicast database (mdb). I check it with:

```
host ~$ sudo bridge -d -s mdb show
dev br0 port vnet0 grp 239.255.255.250 temp  vid 10 257.14
router ports on br0: enp1s0  238.17 temp
```

I have just a upnp client running (grp 239.255.255.250) and use VLAN 10. The guest will still stay in the multicast group for 257.14 seconds if it does not send a igmp REPORT to stay longer. The bridge sees that the next multicast router (the source) is on port **enp1s0** and will kick it out after 238.17 seconds if the source does not send a igmp QUERY before.

On a running multicast stream I see this igmp messages:

```
host ~$ sudo tcpdump -i vnet0 -n igmp
18:38:59.628249 IP 192.168.10.2 > 224.0.0.1: igmp query v3
18:39:02.502110 IP 192.168.10.106 > 224.0.0.22: igmp v3 report, 2 group record(s)
18:41:04.647731 IP 192.168.10.2 > 224.0.0.1: igmp query v3
18:41:13.061858 IP 192.168.10.106 > 224.0.0.22: igmp v3 report, 2 group record(s)
18:43:09.637111 IP 192.168.10.2 > 224.0.0.1: igmp query v3
18:43:19.525836 IP 192.168.10.106 > 224.0.0.22: igmp v3 report, 2 group record(s)
...
```

192.168.10.2 is my internet router (multicast source) and 192.168.10.106 is the guest with streaming client.